# Errors in Safe CLI Tool

Tags: gnosis-safe

[image]

**strong text**

Attempting to use the tool but getting the errors below when executing the first step (pip3 install -U safe-cli) in the guide.

(
PIP Version = 22.3.1 ) (python 3.10)

Comment: Is it okay to continue with the tool showing these errors? If not, what is needed for me to ensure those errors are resolved. Thank you

Comment: If a dependency fails to install usually it means the application might not run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved. I was able to get the application to install with no errors using Linux